# How to convert string in a txt document to code?

Tags: java, arrays, string

I have a text document that has code and Im reading each line as a string, how can I integrate the lines as code?
These are the lines -

```
shape.s(19,1);
shape.line(19,3);
shape.t(19,6);
shape.rotate(grid);
shape.rotate(grid);
```

Each line is saved in a string array like this one:

`r[0]="shape.s(19,1);"`

Comment: (About the duplicate, ignore the selected answer. It doesn't apply to your case)

Comment: You have to write code to parse the String commands and execute the associated Graphics2D drawShape methods.